# SCP first line of a file to another system

Tags: linux, scp

I think it should be possible to use a combination of the scp command and the head command to copy only the first line of a file to a remote system, but haven't been able to come up with the right command to make it happen.

Given an scp command like this:

```
scp /shared/myfolder/myfile.txt myuser@myserver:/newlocation/myotherfolder/myfile.txt
```

I'd like to send only the first line of myFile.txt to the remote system. I could use this command first:

```
head -1 myfile.txt >> myfile2.txt
```

and then scp myfile2.txt, but it would be helpful to have this in a single command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scp doesn't read from stdin or work with bash process substitution, but you can
try hacks like:

```
head -1 myfile.txt | ssh  myuser@myserver "cat > /shared/myfolder/myfile.txt"
```